# Что означает эта ассемблерная инструкция в С++ коде?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, gcc

Решил в годболте ([ссылка](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zasfrE1sz)) посмотреть ассемблерный код простейшей функции:

```
struct strr {

    int i;

};

int main(){

    strr strrr{};
    strr strrr2{};

    return 0;

}
```

Годболт выдал вот такой ассемблерный код, ответственный за выделение памяти для структуры:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
    mov     eax, 0
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Я не могу понять, что делает `mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0 mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0`. Интуитивно я понимаю, что число после `rbp-` - это что-то вроде смещения адреса, относительно начала стека. Но не могу понять, во-первых, если rbp - это указатель на начало стека, то почему мы вычитаем из него размер структуры, чтобы получить адрес? Во-вторых, что значит DWORD PTR? Компилятор gcc

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy так.. Ага... То есть у стека вершиной называется, объективно, его низ? Если рассматривать адреса так, что меньшие адреса (например 0х0000) вверху, а большие (например 0хFFFF) - внизу, то вершина будет "расти" в сторону адреса 0xFFFF? То есть вершина, но растет вниз? :/

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я когда-то видел картинку с попыткой объяснить какой-то подобный механизм, я так понимаю, что ноги оттуда растут?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy довольно забавное сравнение) Итого, получается, что rbp-4 - это мы получаем адрес от начала стека, смещенный на 4 байта. Тогда что такое DWORD PTR?

Comment: DWORD PTR - указатель на двойное слово. У вас там `int` - это двойное слово.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy но что он означает в данной инструкции? Зачем это нужно в mov?

Comment: [Время пришло...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8)

Comment: Это конструктор обнуляет поле в вашей структуре.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy сейчас сопоставил информацию из гугла с тем, что вы говорите. Поправьте меня, если я неправильно понял. DWORD PTR означает, что мы вставляем 0 сразу в 4 байта, поскольку размер `int` - 4 байта? То есть эта инструкция была бы аналогична последовательности `mov rbp-4, 0 mov rbp-5, 0 mov rbp-6, 0 mov rbp-7, 0`?

Comment: @wololo действительно пришло) Никогда не думал, что когда-либо полезу в ассемблер) Спасибо за ссылку на темы с книгами

Comment: Вы понимаете правильно. Вам нужно найти книгу по ассемблеру и пролистать. Через две недели будете мне всё объяснять.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy просто перед прочтением мне нужно было ознакомиться с несколькими деталями, чтобы сделать себе отправную точку. Так что за книги обязательно сяду)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy единственное, поправлюсь. Я сказал, что стек растет от адресов 0x0000 к 0xffff (Условно), но начало стека все таки расположено в больших адресах и растет к меньшим. То есть от адресов 0xffff к 0x0000. Если инициализировать две переменные `int` и вывести адрес сначала той, что первая, а потом той, что вторая, то адрес первой будет больше, чем у второй. По крайней мере в gcc, проверил только что - https://godbolt.org/z/f896b88ce

Comment: Я вам все наврал про направление стека. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33583134/14775762

Comment: @ComeInRag, запись с отрицательным смещением от текущего стека - это обращение к локальным переменным процедуры\функции. Если-же смещение положительное, то это обращение к аргументам функции. Кроме того встречаются и инструкции типа `sub rsp,20h` - это выделение 32-байт памяти в стеке, соответственно `add rsp,20h` является освобождением выделенной памяти.